# The purpose of starting an initial comment with /*! in JavaScript and CSS files

Tags: javascript, css

I've noticed that initial comment in JavaScript or CSS files is sometimes started with `/*!`.
What is the purpose of the explanation mark?

For example, [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery):

```
/*! jQuery v1.7.1 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */
```

[Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29):

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v2.0.1
 *
 * Copyright 2012 Twitter, Inc
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It tells compression tools such as the [YUICompressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/) and [Uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/), which minify the code, to leave the commented section in place as they usually remove all comments from the code.

Comment: Is there a way to override this without removing the !?  I'm using Uglify and I need to remove all blocks so I can inject the CSS file into my HTML.

Comment: Of course, the point of leaving these comments in, usually, is because they are licensing messages that are required to be included with any distributed versions of the code.

Comment: Licenses are meant to be always present with code so you may violate some rights by removing them.

Comment: Now deprecated?

Answer (score 4):

I believe one purpose of the exclamation point is to tell JavaScript [minifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) to leave these particular comments in, when condensing the files.

Answer (score 4):

Some software like [Coda](http://panic.com/coda/) also support the "bookmark syntax" shown below, so that one can navigate to different parts of code through the app's code navigator.

```
// !bookmark
/* !bookmark */
<!-- !bookmark -->
```

Note that in the examples above there's a space between the comment syntax the exclamation mark.

Answer (score 0):

It is also important for **attribution** for the author of external dependencies/API, especially free ones.

When minifying, the least we can do is to offer them some bytes of recognition.

e.g.    `/*! PhotoSwipe main CSS by Dmitry Semenov | photoswipe.com | MIT license */`
will not be erased by minifier.