# JS libraries: what's with the exclamation point in the comment block?

Tags: javascript, comments

I've noticed a number of javascript libraries have an odd exclamation mark at the beginning of their comment blocks like so:

```
/*!
 * some jQuery plugin
 * MIT license
 */
```

Does this signify something?

A few examples:

- https://github.com/desandro/masonry/blob/master/masonry.js
- https://github.com/ed-lea/jquery-collagePlus/blob/master/jquery.collagePlus.min.js
- https://github.com/GBKS/Wookmark-jQuery/blob/master/jquery.wookmark.min.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, it's just a marker that javascript minifiers look for, so they don't strip the comment. There is no particular meaning to it.

Comment: Also see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248363/the-purpose-of-starting-an-initial-comment-with-in-javascript-and-css-files