# Question about javascript function structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a codebase of javascript that I am working on, and have encountered a piece of structure that I am not familiar with. I would just like the name of it so I know what to look up and read about. Any additional information is appreciated.

This is in a Node.js/express environment.

What I'm specifically asking about is the `fizz` thing in `file2.js`, referenced in the line marked with a `/*!!*/` in `file1.js`. It looks like some sort of wrapper around a series of functions. What is its proper name?

```
//file1.js

const file2 = require('filepath/file2')

foo.get('/bar', (req, res) => {
    file2.fizz.buzz(req.field.item, res)   /*!!*/
    localfunction(param1, param2)
})
```

```
//file2.js
module.exports = {
  fizz: {
      buzz: (str, res) => {
          console.log("buzz")
      },
      bang: (param1, param2) => {
          console.log("bang!")
      }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Im not sure what is your question. if you are asking about the `/*! */` sign here is a good answer for it https://stackoverflow.com/a/11248430/9453736

Comment: An object? Or the word `fizz` itself? An object property (`fizz` being the property name, the object being the property value)? You might want to take a quick step back and spin through a JS tutorial real quick.

Comment: `module.exports = {}` -> module.exports is an object; `fizz: {}` -> the property `fizz` on `module.exports` is also an object;` buzz: (str, res) => {...}` -> the property `buzz` on `module.exports.fizz` is a function. `x = require('file2.js'); x.fizz.buzz()` is how you access that function.

Comment: Is there a name for wrapping multiple functions together like this in the `fizz` object?

Comment: The name for 'wrapping' multiple anything together in that format is simply called an object. You might also call it a 'map'

Comment: I guess you might call it a `<string -> function> map` or something, not sure

Comment: Awesome, this is all good info. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fizz` is a **property** name (on the object referenced by the `file2` variable).

---

Further Reading:

- [Object basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics#Object_basics) on MDN.